# Is 10% the "best" percentage shown in "top tags"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

I've only ever seen top 10%, 20% and 30% as the percentages for the user's "best" tags listed at the top of a Careers profiles.

Are better percentages possible?  Is there any interest in adding top 5% or even 1% ranks?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Are better percentages possible?

No, `Top 10%` is the [highest it goes](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jonskeet).  And by highest I of course mean lowest; 10% is the *best* percentage careers is capable of displaying.

Comment: On Careers 3.0 I hear it will [go to 11%](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1H6yT.png).

Comment: @jadarnel27 - gah, now I want to re-word it, but I don't want to kill your joke :)

Comment: Reword away, my joke did not take that much effort =)

Answer (score 8):

I would like to see more detail than the top 10% implemented in Careers.

There is a contra argument to be made that membership of anything over the top 10% may be temporary, and I accept this - perhaps something like a "high water mark" could be displayed, together with a date?

Comment: I agree with this. Given the actual number of people who are _actively_ participating, a seasoned SOer reading your profile will know that top 10% is very vague and does not indicate an achievement.

Answer (score 0):

Much has changed since you asked your question. Currently, the **top 1%** mark would the best achievement one can obtain in a given tag. The top 5% mark has been added as well. Cody Gray's [story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/366904) is a great illustration of both.